# Remove duplicates in Content Query web part

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

I'm looking to use the Content Query web part in Sharepoint 2010 to return items from a list. What I'm trying to do is return a list of categories available from all the items available. This is bringing back duplicates in the list. Does anyone know if there is a way in the xsl style sheets to remove/hide these duplicates? Or possibly a setting on the web part I've overlooked.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove duplicates in [CQWP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms492595%28v=office.12%29.aspx) using Xslt based approach the grouping capabilities could be used.

### Input data

Suppose we have a list with the following customers

```
Customer A
Customer A
Customer B
Customer C
Customer C
Customer C
Customer D
```

Let's see how CQWP could be configured to display results without duplicates

### Enable grouping

First step to enable grouping by customer name (title column) as shown on picture below

[image]

The CQWP results should look like this

[image]

### Customize the results

Now our goal to transform results in such a way that only marked items will be displayed

Save a copy of `ContentQueryMain.xsl` and modify it as described below

First, create the template for rendering grouped item

```
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.CallGroupItem">
      <xsl:param name="CurPosition" />
      <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginListItem" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="itemstyle">
              <xsl:with-param name="CurPos" select="$CurPosition" />
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginList" />
    </xsl:template>
```

and then modify `OuterTemplate.Body` to render grouped item

```
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.Body">
      <xsl:param name="Rows" />
      <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
      <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
      <xsl:variable name="BeginColumn1" select="string('&lt;ul class=&quot;dfwp-column dfwp-list&quot; style=&quot;width:')" />
      <xsl:variable name="BeginColumn2" select="string('%&quot; &gt;')" />
      <xsl:variable name="BeginColumn" select="concat($BeginColumn1, $cbq_columnwidth, $BeginColumn2)" />
      <xsl:variable name="EndColumn" select="string('&lt;/ul&gt;')" />
      <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
            <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &gt;= $FirstRow and $CurPosition &lt;= $LastRow)">
                <xsl:variable name="StartNewGroup" select="@__begingroup = 'True'" />
                <xsl:variable name="StartNewColumn" select="@__begincolumn = 'True'" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$cbq_isgrouping != 'True'">
                        <xsl:if test="$CurPosition = $FirstRow">
                            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginColumn" />
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$StartNewGroup and $StartNewColumn">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$CurPosition = $FirstRow">
                                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginColumn" />
                                <!--xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallHeaderTemplate"/-->
                                <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallGroupItem">
                                     <xsl:with-param name="CurPosition" select="$CurPosition" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallFooterTemplate"/>
                                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat($EndColumn, $BeginColumn)" />
                                <!--xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallHeaderTemplate"/-->
                                <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallGroupItem">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurPosition" select="$CurPosition" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                             </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$StartNewGroup">
                        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallFooterTemplate"/>
                        <!--xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallHeaderTemplate"/-->
                        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallGroupItem">
                           <xsl:with-param name="CurPosition" select="$CurPosition" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$StartNewColumn">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$CurPosition = $FirstRow">
                                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$BeginColumn" />
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat($EndColumn, $BeginColumn)" />
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <!--xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallItemTemplate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="CurPosition" select="$CurPosition" />
                </xsl:call-template-->
                <xsl:if test="$CurPosition = $LastRow">
                  <xsl:if test="$cbq_isgrouping = 'True'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallFooterTemplate"/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$EndColumn" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

You could find the source code [here](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/5375785)

The last step is to replace [Main Xsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.cmsdataformwebpart.mainxsllink%28v=office.12%29.aspx) with custom one (for example, 
export web part and specify [Main Xsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.cmsdataformwebpart.mainxsllink%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property)

For more information about customizing CQWP please follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff380147%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article.

### Result

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [this blog post](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/generating-tag-cloud-content-query-web-part/) from Waldek?

It is about generating a Tag cloud from categories. It seems very similar to your scenario.

Especially this quote:

> We can retrieve all the different categories using one single XPath
> function (→ means a forced line break. In the real code it would be in
> one line):

```
<xsl:variable name="TagsArray" 
select="Row[not(@Category=preceding-sibling::Row/@Category)]/@Category"/>
```

> Although it seems pretty complex it works
> very simple: for each node the value of the Category attribute is
> being compared the value of the Category attribute of the previous
> sibling node. Because the function is included in a not clause we will
> get all the distinct categories.

My tip is to read the blogpost and try modifying it to your specific scenario!