# How to remove duplicates documents from Content Query

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, query, content, duplicate

Having difficulty removing duplicate documents within Content Query.

So far...I have inserted a Content Query Web Part from Content Rollup, SharePoint 2013. This pulls data from a number of different folders and on occasions, the same document is displayed in a number of these folders. I want the Content Query to only display this document once on the home page, but for the life of my can't figure out how to do this... all I've came across so far is about the Search Results but I need do this in Content Query please.

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplications in Content Query web part, we need to customize the Content Query web part programmatically.

Group the items by title in the Content Query tool pane, and create template for grouped items in a copy of ContentQueryMain.xsl file.

More detailed information you can check the similar post: [Remove duplicates in Content Query web part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65550/remove-duplicates-in-content-query-web-part)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've seen this prior to posting, but as I'm not grouping my items in anyway, didn't think this would be appropriate? I'm also finding it difficult to locate any other examples but surely someone must have done this previously. Confused at the moment...